# Which statements are true regarding an energy pyramid?

Tags: zoology

The number of producers is greater than the number of primary consumers.

The amount of energy at the primary consumer level is greater than the amount of energy at the secondary consumer level.

The number of primary consumers is less than the number of secondary consumers.

The amount of energy at the producer level is less than the amount of energy at the primary consumer level.

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to do your homework for you.